# .HTACCESS - Prevention of 404 with no URL query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess to re-write some of my URLs for my web application. The following is used to make the `user` page a little prettier when user_urls (practically a URL friendly username) are passed to it:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) /user?url=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

When I input the URL `http://example.com/user`, the page redirects just fine, and the PHP handles the lack of the query string. However, when the server receives the request of `http://example.com/user/`, it returns a 404 error.

How can I prevent this from happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to the correct URL by prepending a rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

or append `/?` to your regexp.

Comment: This will cause redirect loop if a directory is requested

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/?$ user.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ user.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```